# iOS 8 NSURLCache issue

Tags: ios, caching, ios8, afnetworking, nsurlcache

I'm creating an app where I would like to use cached responses from time to time. I ran into a weird issue related to NSURLCache, more spicifically, if I set NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad on my request, I don't get a cached response on iOS 8. Here's the code I'm using with AFNetworking to get this working:

```
// Define web request.
void (^simpleBlock)(void) = ^{
    GTSessionManager.manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;

    [GTSessionManager.manager POST:string parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSDictionary *responseJson = responseObject;

        [self parseJsonSuccess:responseJson];
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        if (error.userInfo[JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey]) {
            NSData *data = error.userInfo[JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey];

            NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                                       error:&error];

            [self parseJsonError:json];
        }
        else
            [self parseJsonError:nil];
    }];
};

if (self.shouldUseCache) {
    GTSessionManager.manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad;

    [GTSessionManager.manager POST:string parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSDictionary *responseJson = responseObject;

        [self parseJsonCacheSuccess:responseJson];

        // Load second request.
        simpleBlock();
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        simpleBlock();
    }];
}
else
    simpleBlock();
```

The main idea here is that if the the client wants to use a cache, the first request should try to load it, pass the result to the handler and start reloading the request to refresh the cache.

This approach works well on iOS 7 but doesn't work on iOS 8+. I've setup the NSURLCache with the following call.

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:500 * 1024 * 1024
                                                            diskCapacity:500 * 1024 * 1024
                                                                diskPath:@"cache" /**Tried nil here as well. */];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

I read a few articles and other SO questions about this but I just can't get this to work. Am I missing something? Could it be related to the fact that I'm using a POST request?

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention that I'm not using a cache policy on my server. I also tried setting a cache policy using `Cache-Control=max-age=604800, public` but I got the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after some further investigation, I concluded that the problem is somewhere in `NSURLSession`. I sent the exact same requests as above but using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` instead of `AFHTTPSessionManager` and the cache loads perfectly on iOS 8+.

Not quite sure where the problem is still though, I think it has something to do with the cache policies but for now I'm sticking with `NSURLConnection`.